# How can my website host prevent a JavaScript on my page to run?

Tags: javascript, webserver

Here's my page, with a small alert statement in JavaScript. But it won't run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>alert("hei");</script>
Running JS alert
</body>
</html>
```

[As link](https://files.itslearning.com/data/124/24137/testjs.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console you will find the following:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://statics.itslearning.com https://cdn.itslearning.com https://eu1statics.itslearning.com https://us1statics.itslearning.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lGrjoiPwYPWwQzxw5c0TicyWiXm0QDxMURqig0RQtv4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Your hosting is setting the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) to run scripts only from script tags linking to the following URLs:

```
https://statics.itslearning.com
https://cdn.itslearning.com
https://eu1statics.itslearning.com
https://us1statics.itslearning.com
```

You need to remove the inline-script and move it to a file linked from these pages.

Answer (score -1):

Because security settings on itslearning.com don't allow inline scripts. Just create a separate file for your js and include it into the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
<script>alert("hei");</script>
```

with

```
<button onclick="alert('i am script')">click me</button>
```

due to some restriction inline js is getting block . for more detail go to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution